# Cannot log into new GitLab installation

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-auto-devops

I have recently installed an instance of GitLab CE using Docker. The application sits behind an Nginx proxy and I can access the login page without problems.

Unfortunately, I also cannot log into GitLab.

Apparently, some of the startup documentation for GitLab is out of date. Instead of a setup page that allows you to set the admin username and password (as some documentation describes), there is a login page that has a link to a registration page. The registration page does not accept registrations without an administrator's approval, and there is no administrator to approve it.

Looking at the GitLab documentation, there are several references to a "default administrator" login and password. Unfortunately, those defaults are not provided.

Searches on the Internet have yielded several possible default admins, none of which work. The most common defaults named in several places are "root" (username) and "5iveL!fe" (password). This does not work, either.

I am hoping that someone can tell me how I can get into my GitLab application, because right now the system is completely unusable.

Can anyone help with this?